# Android device with 577ppi pixel- does it belong to xxhdpi? or xxxhdpi?

Tags: android

I am developing a android application, I am confused when developing for S6 device.. Its density is 577ppi pixels. Does it belong to xxhdpi? or xxxhdpi?

Comment: Please save this for future use: https://www.google.com/design/tool/devices/

In your case, I guess xxxhdpi will fit your density

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html